# Make tabsetPanel fix in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to fix the tabs position in shiny, so that when I scroll down the tabs must be visible at the top. This will help to quickly navigate to other tabs without scrolling to the top of the page when I at the bottom of the page.

I got a solution to fix the sidebarpanel at 
[Make sidebarPanel autoscroll with mainPanel in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972650/make-sidebarpanel-autoscroll-with-mainpanel-in-shiny#), but the same technique I am unable to apply to fix the tabsetpanel.

Please help.